# Resource constrained devices

Tags: memory, device, hardware

Why are the resource constrained devices resource constrained in context to Internet of Things?

Why don't we just arrange for more memory or processing power or battery power in it?

Memory and processor related hardware these days are very compact and cheap in case of memory too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Memory and processor related hardware these days are very compact and cheap in case of memory too."

If you buy one or two, yes. IoT devices are considered for large volumes. A few dollars here and there start to add up when you buy millions of them.

Another issue is heat. A fast processor generates more heat, which can be a real problem if they're literally inside a wall.

Comment: And of course more processing power results in higher power usage as well.